# Pros and Cons: Software Patent vs Restrictive Open Source

Tags: open, source

At times I have considered going down the open source route, while at other times I have felt that perhaps a patent might be more suitable. I have a general understanding of both approaches, but am wondering what the practical implications of these two pathways are nowadays in realistic terms.

For example, I am inspired by the notion an open source environment might encourage the sharing of ideas, where other users contribute code. But the skeptic in me feels that most people who access open source libraries will be takers and not givers. That is, they will be passive users and not contribute anything at all.

Comment: Is this question not simply equivalent to "do you want protection for your idea or not?"? Because if so, this would be purely opinion-based, and so unanswerable.

Comment: Have a look at this company for a very good example how open source may benefit you: http://mobilecg.hu/about_us.html

Comment: These are not mutually exclusive. You can't patent the code itself, only the application of an algorithm to a specific application. There is nothing keeping you form getting a patent and open sourcing the code.